# Faster way to concatenate vectors repeatedly

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, vector, concatenation

Is there a faster way to concatenate matrix like this code below? These lines of code will be called thousands of times, thus it's very time consuming. For 1658880 calls, I get 15 seconds for just one slice! (I have around 2000 slices, so total number of calls would be 1658880*2000 times!)

```
a=rand(1,100);
b=rand(1,100);
c=rand(1,100);
d=rand(1,100);

k=([b; b; b; d; ones(100); c; a; a; a]);
```

**EDIT**

Suggestion by Dev-iL (with `repmat`):

```
k=zeros(9,100);
k(1:3,:)=repmat(b,3,1);
k(4,:)=d;
k(5,:)=ones(size(a));
k(6,:)=d;
k(7:9,:)=repmat(a,3,1);
```

without `repmat`

```
k=zeros(9,100);
k(1,:)=b;
k(2,:)=b;
k(3,:)=b;
k(4,:)=d;
k(5,:)=ones(size(a));
k(6,:)=d;
k(7,:)=a;
k(8,:)=a;
k(9,:)=a;
```

With `repmat`, it's slower than the original code by 11 seconds. Without `repmat`, I actually get 15 seconds faster!

I'd appreciate any more suggestions and help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not preallocate the final size and then put elements in correct positions via indexing? You can also use multidimensional arrays for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you tell me more about the indexing? I can head start from there

Comment: This is the [first](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) result in google. There are [other useful ones](https://www.google.com/search?q=matlab+matrix+indexing) as well.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm quite familiar with that. But I can't think of the way using the indexing to get my matrix `k` though

Comment: It is better that `a,b,c,d` to be column vectors ad concatenate them as `[b b b d ones(100) c a a a]`. also as @Dev-iL suggested preallocation of `k` can be useful.

Comment: With the data in your example, you would `k = zeros(9,100);` then `k(1:3,:) = repmat(b, ...); k(4,:) = d;` etc. Though maybe no repmatting and just doing `k(1,:) = b; k(2,:) = b; ...` would be better. This needs to be benchmarked.

Comment: Without `repmat` I get 15 seconds faster! I edited the question, do have a look :)

Comment: Consider that `ones(size(a))` is different than `ones(100)`. The first is a `[1 100]` matrix and the second is a `[100 100]` matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in MATLAB data is stored in [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) order it is better to generate `a,b,c,d` as column vectors and concatenate them as:

```
a=rand(100,1);
b=rand(100,1);
c=rand(100,1);
d=rand(100,1);
one = ones(100);
k= [b b b d one c a a a];
```

Instead you can pre-allocate `k` and fill it as:

```
k = ones(100,108); %preallocation
%in the loop you can fill it:
k(:,1)=b;
k(:,2)=b;
k(:,3)=b;
k(:,4)=d;
k(:,105)=c;
k(:,106)=a;
k(:,107)=a;
k(:,108)=a;
```

Comment: Excellent find, as an extension, is there any viability for this for other operations? For example, is rand(100,1).*rand(100,1) faster than rand(1,100).*rand(1,100)

Comment: For vectors I think there is no difference but when we want to concatenate them as matrix It differs.

Comment: Thanks, did some testing and it appears that at least for dot multiplication it doesn't have a statistical improvement. It's always nice to learn the little tricks though.